# How to get device IMEI after user grant permission?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I need to retrieve the device IMEI right after the user has grant the permission. The sample code of the plugin stated that the IMEI can be retrieve after user grant permission and restart the app (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/uid). The plugin will always return blank if the app is not restarted. Is there any way to get the IMEI right after the app get the permission? Please help.

This is my current code:

```
async getImei(): Promise<string> {
        const { hasPermission } = await this.androidPermissions.checkPermission(
            this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_PHONE_STATE
        );

        if (!hasPermission) {
            const result = await this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(
                this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_PHONE_STATE
            );

            if (!result.hasPermission) {
                throw new Error('Permissions required');
            }

            return this.getImei(); // i tried to call itself again but still no luck
        }

        return this.uid.IMEI
    }
```